# How to open TimeSpanPicker on a Button (Coding4Fun toolkit)

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have button and TimeSpanPicker in XAML.

```
<Image x:Name="sleepButton" Source="img/Sleep.png"
       Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
       Stretch="None" Tap="sleepButton_Tap"/>

<controls:TimeSpanPicker x:Name="timespanPicker" Step="0:5" Value="0:0"
                         PickerPageUri="timePickerPage"
                         Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
                         Visibility="Collapsed" IsEnabled="False" />
```

And here is my code.

```
private void sleepButton_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpanPicker timespanPicker = new TimeSpanPicker();
    timespanPicker.PickerPageUri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    timespanPicker.OpenPicker();
}
```

Then I click the button do nothing. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is your PickerPageUri correct? Are you navigating to the same form that contains the SleepButton? i.e. MainPage.xaml to MainPage.xaml?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. How I must change the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PickerPageUri is if you have a custom picker control such as a single button to set the date/time, not to show the TimeSpanPicker. You're also creating a new instance of TimeSpanPicker here essentially overriding your xaml:

```
private void sleepButton_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpanPicker timespanPicker = new TimeSpanPicker();
    ...
```

You should just be able to call `timespanPicker.OpenPicker();`. Not sure if you'll need to enable it, but yes, have the visibility collapsed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the PickerPageUri to something other than the MainPage.xaml. The intention is to navigate to another page so that you can use this other page to set the time. The following article should help you with this :-

http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-TimeSpanPicker-in-depth

Comment: I read that article, but there are not told about it. I create new page and change Uri to it. But it's just opening this page now. What I must add in xaml of my new page?

Comment: Did you look at the associated articles, in particular this one : http://blogs.xamlninja.com/blend/wp7-contrib-customising-the-datetime-picker