# How to emulate a Tap Event in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How I can emulate a tap on a `TimeSpanPicker(coding4fun)` in code?

I tried it with `TimeSpanPicker1.Focus()`, but nothing happens.

Comment: Simulating clicks / taps / keypresses always seems like a hack to me... what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I have a label and a time span on the same position. Now I would like that when the end user taps on the label, the TimeSpanPicker shall open.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319568/how-to-open-timespanpicker-on-a-button-coding4fun-toolkit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call TimeSpanPicker1.OpenPicker(); on the Tap from your label.

http://coding4fun.codeplex.com samples should have any edge case issue like what you are looking for.